# Python Pandas rolling window apply multiple lambda functions

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

Is it possible to apply more than one function to a pandas rolling window in a tuple like fashion?

I'm currently creating returning the count, lower bound and upper bound of the largest bin by count of a price series over a rolling window.

```
def qcut_data(x):
    data_out = pd.qcut(x, q = 10, duplicates = 'drop').value_counts().nlargest(1)
    return data_out


df_m['hist_count'] = df_m['mid'].rolling(window = rolling_window).apply(lambda x: qcut_data(x).item())
df_m['hist_bottom'] = df_m['mid'].rolling(window = rolling_window).apply(lambda x: qcut_data(x).index[0].left)
df_m['hist_top'] = df_m['mid'].rolling(window = rolling_window).apply(lambda x: qcut_data(x).index[0].right)
```

This strikes me as horribly inefficient as i'm just returning different values (item and index) of the same function (qcut_data), over the same rolling window of the same Series (df_m['mid']).

Is there a way to combine these so all three values can be returned?

I can't call a list, tuple or set in the .apply() method, is there another way?

Answer (score 7):

You can probably do what you want with [aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) which is more flexible...

```
df_m['mid'].rolling(window=rolling_window).agg([lambda x: qcut_data(x).item(),
                                                lambda x: qcut_data(x).index[0].left,
                                                lambda x: qcut_data(x).index[0].right])
```

But you need to massage the resulting frame to join it. You could also name the lambdas or make them proper funcs.